# Calling a Success script if @Ajax call succeed

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following javascript which contains an ajax call:-

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: '@Url.Action("DeleteSelected"),
    data: { ids: boxData.join(",") }
  })
    });
```

but is there a way to call a javaScript function is the above Ajax call  succeed?
Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
function mySuccessFunction() {
    alert('success');
}

$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: '@Url.Action("DeleteSelected")',
    data: { 
        ids: boxData.join(",") 
    },
    success: function(data) {
        // your code if AJAX call finished successfully
        // call your function that already loaded from here:
        mySuccessFunction();
        // you can also process returned data here            
    }
});
```

Comment: no i already have the function loaded , i just want to call it

Comment: call that method from the success handler

Comment: @johnG: What do you want then? The success delegate is called when the call was successful. You can call any method in there.

Comment: You should mention the `.sucess()` method on the `$` object :]

Comment: this is my question , not sure how i can call a javaScript function form insdie the success ?

Comment: See edited example. Still can't realize what the problem is. That's very basic thing.

Answer (score 0):

You have three particular handlers you can use to process information returned with AJAX, .success(), .done(), and .fail().  With these methods, your code might look something like this:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: '@Url.Action("DeleteSelected"),
    data: { ids: boxData.join(",") }
}).success(function(data) {
    // This callback is executed ONLY on successful AJAX call.
    var returnedJSON = data; // The information returned by the server
    yourSuccessFunction();
}).done(function() {
    // This callback is ALWAYS executed once the AJAX is complete
    yourDoneFunction();
}).fail(function() {
    // This callback is executed ONLY on failed AJAX call.
});
```

Also see: [jQuery AJAX Documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/)